# Implement generic map

Tags: java, dictionary, generics

I have an object (Object o) which has as an attribute a parent class which has two abstract methods and a map as an attribute. One is validateMap() and the other extractMap(). Then I have two child classes where I implement these two methods and using the extractMap() method  set the super map. What I am trying to do is depending on some business logic , each child class to define a different type of map.

```
ParentClass parent = new ParentClass();
Object o = new Object();
if (business logic deciding which type of map needed TypeA or TypeB){

ChildClassTypeA childClassA = new ChildClassA();
childClassA.extractMap();
o.setPArentClass(childClassA);
}
```

```
ParentClass{

public Map <? , ? > map
abstract void extract()
abstract void validate()
}

ChildClassTypeA{

public void extract(){

 Map<String, TypeA > map = new Map<>();
 super.setMap(map);
}

public void validate(){}
}
ChildClassTypeB{

public void extract(){

 Map<String, TypeB > map = new Map<>();
 super.setMap(map);
}

public void validate(){}

}
```

My problem here is how to define the map attribute in the parent class in order to be able to accept the two different types through the child classes

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. You are missing `class` keywords, semi-colons etc. all over the place. You can't instantiate a map `Map<>()`  as it's an interface

Comment: Yes sorry about that I wrote it as an example. It is not the syntax that bothers me. Its how to define the Map in the super class in order  to accept either Map<String, TypeA> or Map<String,TypeB> .

Comment: It already does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a generic parameter T to the ParentClass and use it in the map definition. Now any class that extends ParentClass must specify the type of the map values.

```
import java.util.Map;

public abstract class ParentClass<T> {
    public Map <String , T > map;
    abstract void extract();
    abstract void validate();

    protected void setMap(Map <String , T > pMap)
    {
        this.map=pMap;
    }
}
```

And the child class look like:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class ChildClassTypeA extends ParentClass<TypeA> {

    @Override
    void extract() {
        Map<String,TypeA> myMap=new HashMap<>();
        setMap(myMap);
    }

    @Override
    void validate() {

    }
}
```

Now you can even let ParentClass instantiate the map:

```
public abstract class ParentClass<T> {
    public Map <String , T > map = new HashMap<>();
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I was doing half of the things you said by I did not define the parent class as a generic therefore I could not use the generic T to the map. Your sollution worked for me